# How to hint to users that they can scroll?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, .net

I was wondering if there is any built-in way to show users that there is more content that they can scroll to *besides* the appearance of a scrollbar.

A scrollbar appears on the right. Someone reading content might not look there. If there is some way to hint to users **at the bottom of the currently visible content** that there is more content that they can scroll to, that would be nice.

Of course we can do anything in code, but that would be too time-consuming (at least to do well). So I was wondering if there is some **CSS** or **HTML** property that can be used for this, or perhaps some **Asp.net** element.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the usual pattern of users really don't look at the scroll bar at the right side of the screen, but also, normally people willing to read more content tend to scroll it using their mouses, so popping up that there's more things below the main part of content it's a silly assumption that the users can't scroll on their mouses as they normally do.

**BUT**, answering your question, you can use **HTML**, **CSS** and **jQuery** to add a fixed icon on bottom left or (more likely), bottom right corner of the screen, showing with an arrow that they can go to the next "chapter" or etc, you'd use hashes calling IDs over DIVs and as the user clicks the arrow, they'd be redirected just down below to continue reading. Not that fancy to code this, but it's pretty decent stuff. Comment below if you're wondering to see an example and I'd be glad to help and code a simple example for you.

Comment: `people willing to read more content tend to scroll it` - You might be overestimating users. _You_ would scroll. So would most users on this site. Not all users would.